# Is "space expanding" or is "matter explanding"?

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, big-bang, vacuum

The terminology frequently used to describe the Big Bang is that 'space (itself) is expanding'.

Is this technically correct or is it really matter that is expanding into the 'everything, emptiness' that we call space?

Comment: Please only ask one question per post.

Answer (score 1):

> If that's true what happens when the volume of a container,
> 'containing' a vacuum, is increased? Is space literally expanding in
> that container?

No, for the reason that the *metric of space* hasn't changed when the container volume is increased, i.e., the measured distance between two points within the container is the same before and after container volume increases.

This isn't the case for the [metric expansion of space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_expansion_of_space):

> The expansion of the universe is the increase of the distance between
> two distant parts of the universe with time. It is an intrinsic
> expansion whereby the **scale of space itself changes**. The universe
> does not expand "into" anything and does not require space to exist
> "outside" it. Technically, neither space nor objects in space move.
> **Instead it is the metric governing the size and geometry of spacetime itself that changes in scale**.

(emphasis mine)

Comment: The two points being measured inside the container ... are they measured from outside the container? ... a different frame?  

What changes inside the container when it expands? 

"Instead it is the metric governing the size and geometry of spacetime itself that changes in scale."

Isn't this what I said? ... that there's really no such thing as space ... it's really the distance between things ... just as there's no such thing as time, it's really the number of events between events.

Answer (score 0):

No, a vacuum is not the same as outer space. That's because [outer space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_space) is not empty:

> Outer space, or just space, is the expanse that exists beyond the Earth and between celestial bodies. Outer space is not completely empty—it is a hard vacuum containing a low density of particles, predominantly a plasma of hydrogen and helium, as well as electromagnetic radiation, magnetic fields, neutrinos, dust, and cosmic rays.

Answer (score 0):

If you enlarge a container that has a vacuum in it, yes you have a larger container. The available space in it is greater, however you still have nothing in it. Outer space is not a perfect vacuum, there are thinly scattered gas and dust particles.